# problematic rotate() function ~ transform rotate and translate not working for single element

Tags: html, css, rotation

I am trying to rotate the button 180 degrees. I found out that when the 'rotate()' function is called before the 'translate()' one, the rotation doesn't work.

My question is: Why it works like that?

1st code(not working):

```
   .btn--right {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
```

2nd code(working):

```
   .btn--right {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your second example is fully working? What happened to the translations? You can put several transforms into one transform: setting but you can't have one transform property following another as the first will be overwritten by the second.

Comment: @AHaworth Second example is not working because he mentioned `transform` on two separate lines. I addressed the second part of your comment in my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because you cannot specify two `transform`'s on one element. The second set of CSS is working because the `rotate` is positioned last in the DOM order. Therefore it is overriding the  `translate`. You'll notice if you add `!important;` to your first set of CSS (the one not working), it will work just fine as demonstrated in the snippet.

You can achieve `rotate` and `translate` on a single element you can write it like so:

```css
transform: rotate(180deg) translate(50%, -50%);
```

```css
.btn--right {
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(180deg)!important;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn--right">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second transform property overrides first one

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: translate(50%, -50%);
```

`transform: translate(50%, -50%);` applies

```
transform: translate(50%, -50%);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

`transform: rotate(180deg);` applies

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.btn--right{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  

  right: 0;
  top: 50%;

  
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);


  /* transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: rotate(180deg); */
}

.btn--right p {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn--right">
      <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```